# Binding a dropdown in ASP.NET Core razor page to ado.net stored procedure

Tags: c#, razor, ado.net, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm currently in the process of learning ASP.NET core Razor pages and would like some help please.

I would like to create a drop down containing results from a stored procedure. The SP will bring back two columns: an ID Column and a name column.

I would like the user to be able to pick a name from the drop down for searching purposes, however that can wait.

I've managed to do it before using EF Core however now I'm using ADO.NET and my owm SP which I have no problem with.

So what I have tried so far is:

Model

```
public List<SelectListItem> ProjectList { get; set; }`
```

Below is what I'm trying to use to use to get call a method from a different class to get the data for the drop down`

```
    public IEnumerable<Projects> ProjectList()
    {
        projects = objProject.GetAllProjects().ToList();
        return projects;
    }
```

Then I'm thinking of using HTML tag helpers to create the drop down in the front end however I can't pinpoint how to sort it.

I do think having the IEnumerable isn't right and I should be using `IActionResult`.

I'd be very grateful for any advice or even hints

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For populating the dropdownlist in Asp.net core razor pages, you could use `select` tag helper in the page like below :

```
<select name="Id" asp-items="Model.ProjectList"></select>
```

Then in PageModel

```
public List<SelectListItem> ProjectList { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
      ProjectList = GetProjectList().Select(p => new SelectListItem
      {
            Value=p.Id.ToString(),
            Text=p.Name
      }).ToList();
}
public IEnumerable<Projects> GetProjectList()
{
      var  projects = objProject.GetAllProjects().ToList();
      return projects;
}
```

Reference: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/select-lists

Comment: Thank you for this, it fixed my problem.

By saying sort it in my question, I meant solvie it sorry